# Firestore Database - exporting collections using NPM package

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore-export to get my firestore database for my own archives, this only works for upto 70 records and then cmd freezes.

Any idea or does someone have more experience with these packages.

Thank you for the help

I tried myself to google solutions, I don't want to start using the billing on firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your payment plan to blaze